# How to add UIButton to UITableViewCell dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I wanna add an UIButton to a table cell dynamically - please see the below requirements.

When user selects a cell, I'm simply adjusting the height of that table cell in

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(UIIndexPath*) indexPath {
        selIndPath = [indexPath retain];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The above method forces the tableView to adjust the height of that selected row. But when I added the UIButton in the above method, the button is not visible.

I'm not interested with the [self.tableView reloadData];

Any help greatly appreciated.

********EDITED****************

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (selIndPath && selIndPath == indexPath) {
        //UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//      UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1234];
//      btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24);
//      [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        return 90;
    }
    return 64;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    // THIS LINES OF CODE WORKS ONLY ON reloadData
    if (selIndPath && selIndPath == indexPath) {
        UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24);
        btn.tag = 1234;
        [btn setTitle:@"Hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading..";
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selIndPath = [indexPath retain];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you were using to add the UIButton?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added some more extra code to my question. That might help you to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The addition of the button will not work if you add it to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: . What you need to do is create a custom `UITableViewCell`( Refer to this question's answer on how- [Changing the position of custom UIButton in custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352530/changing-the-position-of-custom-uibutton-in-custom-uitableviewcell))

In the Custom cell, create a method

```
-(void) addButtonToCell
{
   UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24);
    btn.tag = 1234;
    [btn setTitle:@"Hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.contentView addSubview:btn];

}
```

Of course, how you add the button and what arguments you pass to this method is upto you, but you get the gist.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: , simply add

```
if (selIndPath && selIndPath == indexPath) {
[cell addButtonToCell];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works if and only if you call [tableView reloadData]. As said earlier, I'm not interested with reloadData. Since my table has very large data and it voids the animation affect of row height changes.

Comment: @prathumca : how about using this method - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
 on your table view. That will reload only the rows that you want to.

Comment: I was giving a try that, but as of now no luck. The animation is not that much smooth and the buttons are not displayed/aligned correctly. Any help really appreciated.