# dynamically change height of cells in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created an app with a table view. Which uses a view and a label in each cell. But if I create the views and cells in the (!cell) code it returns empty cells and if I remove the (!cell) condition it displays the data but does not take dynamic height. Can anyone please help me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ 
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", LanguageFile]];

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];

self.reloadArray = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Rows"];}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [self.reloadArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Get data for the current row
  NSString *textData = [reloadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]

CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:textData];

    if(dataTextHeight < 44)
    {
        dataTextHeight = 44;
    }

    return dataTextHeight;
}

-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForIndex:(NSString *)string
{
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(280, 10000);

CGSize labelHeightSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

if(labelHeightSize.height < 44){
    labelHeightSize.height = 44;
}

return labelHeightSize.height;
}



-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

static const int textViewTag = 1, textLabelTag = 2;

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_back.png"]];

img.frame = tableView.frame;
tableView.backgroundView = img;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // First view
    UIView *textView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 280.0, 36.00)];
    textView.tag = textViewTag;
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];

    // First label
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 270.0, 36.00)];
    textLabel.tag = textLabelTag;
    textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0f];
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    // textLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
}


    NSString *textData = [reloadArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section)];

    CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:textData];

    UIView *textView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:textViewTag];
    CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, textViewFrame.size.width, dataTextHeight);

    UILabel *textLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:textLabelTag];
    CGRect textLabelFrame = textLabel.frame;
    textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, textLabelFrame.size.width, dataTextHeight);
    textLabel.text = textData;
    textLabel.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.65];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cell.frame.size.height

Comment: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UITableviewCell height dynamically in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846374/change-uitableviewcell-height-dynamically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a part of my code which i used in my app. It works for me fine.Ping me if u need help.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
CGSize constraintSize = {230.0, 20000}; //230 is cell width & 20000 is max height for cell
CGSize neededSize = [ [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];


return MAX(45, neededSize.height +33);


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

{        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


}


CGSize constraintSize = {230.0, 20000};


UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

[label setNumberOfLines:0];

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0f]];

label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
CGSize neededSize = [ [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
// NSLog(@"Height%f",neededSize.height);
//NSLog(@"width%f",neededSize.width);
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ]];

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 230, MAX(neededSize.height+30, 44.0f))];

[[cell contentView] addSubview:label];




cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


return cell;


}
```

Hope it helps.!!!

Comment: I am using xcode 4.6 in which the autorelease and release commands are deprecated . Can anyone please tell me what is the alternative method.

Comment: @NehaDangui Just delete all release/retain/autorelease calls.

Comment: @NehaDangui r u using ARC in  ur project?

Answer (score 6):

I saw a lot of solutions but all was wrong or uncomplet.
You can solve all problems with 5 lines in viewDidLoad and autolayout.
This for objetive C:

```
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;//the estimatedRowHeight but if is more this autoincremented with autolayout
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0) ;
```

For swift 2.0:

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension      
 self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
 self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
 self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now create your cell with xib or into tableview in your Storyboard
With this you no need implement nothing more or override. (Don forget number os lines 0) and the bottom label (constrain) downgrade "Content Hugging Priority -- Vertical to 250"

[image]

You can donwload the code in the next url:
https://github.com/jposes22/exampleTableCellCustomHeight

References: http://candycode.io/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-text-height-using-auto-layout/

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return "your content height";
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.