# UITableViewCell dynamic height programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

How to assign dynamic height to UITableViewCell in UITableViewController dynamically by using UILabel.

Comment: You have to use NSAttributedString for get label height as per contain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609720/dynamically-change-height-of-cells-in-objective-c

Comment: Can u mention why you want to use the label for height @madan gupta

Comment: i want to set dynamic height to UITableViewCell as per height of my UILable's height. Bcos my UILabel may have multiple lines ,so i want to adjust UITableViewCell's height dynamically. And i'm building my UI programmatically....@Cool cracker

Comment: @Madangupta: you mean based on label text length?

Comment: yes. based on label text length and height. @Vineesh TP

Comment: @Madangupta: check my answer. If you are using auto layout. Add the needed constraints also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic tableViewCell height use this.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CGSize labelHeight = [self heigtForCellwithString:yourLabel.text    withFont:yourLabel.font];
    return labelHeight.height; // the return height + your other view height
}

-(CGSize)heigtForCellwithString:(NSString *)stringValue withFont:(UIFont)font{
 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300,9999); // Replace 300 with your label width
  NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
  CGRect rect = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                       options:         (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                    attributes:attributes
                                       context:nil];
    return rect.size;

}
```

Comment: Yes, with little changes...its working ... than

Comment: @Madangupta: if it ok, please accept the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' - Probably not adding anything to NSDictionary *attributes. Does anyone else think this works?

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}
```

in above method you can return one CGFloat variable which have dynamic height of cell for particular index of UITableView

Answer (score 2):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName:     [UIColor blackColor]};
NSString *text = @"Your label text";

CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];

ht = 20;

if (textSize.width > [FunctionUtils getViewWidth]) {

    ht = (textSize.width/([FunctionUtils getViewWidth]));
    ht = (ceil(ht))*20+35;
//20 font size
}

return ht;
}
```