# Dynamically get cell height in heightforrow

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to expand a UITableCell to the size of a UILabel. Here's my code, which doesn't work. Thanks a bunch!

Code:

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(labelWidth,9999); // Replace 300 with your label width //TODO replace
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
CGRect rect = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:constraint
               options:         (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
               attributes:attributes
               context:nil];
return rect.size;
```

Comment: Could you describe the problem/error you have your actual code?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336122/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height-programmatically

Comment: Or you could just use auto layout and systemLayoutForSize ..... which is far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I do it in objective-c like this, find swift equivalent. -

```
    CGRect expectedLabelSize = [commentCell.bodyLabel.text
                                   boundingRectWithSize: size
                                                options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                            attributes:attributes context:nil];

    return expectedLabelSize.height;
```