# How to hide and unhide a imageview in a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, show-hide

I am using a tableview with two rows. Each row having a Label, Button and Image View .Initially the the row height is 50 with no image. When I click the Button in the cell the Image Picker will open and select a image from camera roll. So how can I update the tableview height to 100 with a Image View in cell?

Comment: What have you tried and where did it not work? There are a lot of questions on this site about changing cell height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change UITableviewCell height dynamically in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846374/change-uitableviewcell-height-dynamically-in-iphone)

Comment: Let me explain .I have two cells containg a label of title name " upload check front" a button to its right .when I click the button a picker will open at that time the row need to be update to place that image with in the image view .So my Question is how can I create that imageview before and after image upload from picker and update the roe height for the same

Comment: Initial stage - a button ,a label ,row height - 50.                                         Final stage - a button , a label ,a image view containg  image uploaded from picker (camera roll),row height is  100

Comment: Oh, ok. This should be easily doable with autolayout and constraints. Do you have a custom cell class with a `xib`?

Comment: I am not using autolayout or size classes in this project but the cell I am using  it is of custom xib and I have used autolayout on it .Can you pls send me a demo .Because I m very poor in autolayout and very good in autoresizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using autolayout. If you design your cell like this in a `xib` :

Cell for height 100 :
[image]

With these constraints on the image view :

[image]

It will look like this with height 50 :

[image]

The weird line is the image view that got automatically shrunk by autolayout. It looks bad in interface builder, but will be ok on the device/simulator. The one thing you have to remember about is to simply remove the image (not the image view!) when the cell is at 50 height and set it when it is at 100.

Also I'd recommend you to learn about autolayout as it is a powerful tool.

Comment: Thank You very much @Losiowaty .

Comment: No problem. Also, if you think that this is a correct answer, please mark it as such ( the tick under the downvote button )

Comment: So should i keep any condition for row height at -heightForatIndexpath Because if I am putting static float value does it affect to the constraint ??

Comment: Well, yes. You should return 50 for cells without a photo and 100 for this with one. If you return a constant value from it, nothing will ever change. Also, you don't need to vote on the question, just mark it as accepted.